# Apache redirect to an external address

Tags: apache, jboss, server, virtualhost

I've got a problem with apache configuration. In short: there is a JBoss server with backend and Apache with frontend. Both are independent. There are requests, that are sent to the address like `1.1.1.1:8080/xyz` (to the JBoss server) and I would like to make something like overwritting the `1.1.1.1` address with for example 'jboss' word. Just make it hidden for the person that will use the app and not making it necessary to give that person access to the JBoss server. 
How can  I do it? Should I try configure a VirtualHost or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rewrite to an external server but you can Proxy / Reverse Proxy the requests. Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html